# RuntimeError when running 3D Ken Burns Effect

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a Google Colab of the 3d Ken Burns effect that can be found here
https://colab.research.google.com/github/agmm/colab-3d-ken-burns/blob/master/automatic-3d-ken-burns.ipynb

I've got through most of it (I had to add a line of pip install gevent
       as that was causing another error)

But on the final step I'm getting and error of

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "autozoom.py", line 76, in
>   
>       process_load(npyImage, {})   File "", line 10, in process_load   File "", line 128, in disparity_refinement
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
>   line 550, in **call**
>       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "", line 94, in forward RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input
>   tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two
>   contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.

Would anybody be able to take a look and shed some light on what the error may be.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload a smaller picture in pixel size

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).